# Error = Method Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::save does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I can't add images to the database. I am always getting this error.

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'imageName' => 'required',
        'imagePath' => 'required',
    ]);
    $image->productId = $request->input('productId');
    $image->imageName = $request->input('imageName');

    if (request()->hasFile('imagePath')){
        $image = $request->file('imagePath');
        $imageName = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images/productImages/');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $imageName);
        $image->imagePath = $destinationPath . $imageName;
    }
    $image->imageCode = $request->input('imageCode');
    $image->save(); // error line

    return redirect()->route('image.index');
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: That is not an error. Where/what is your the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually from your code what I can understand is that you have an eloquent object and you want to upload an image and save the image data to eloquent object,

but inside your `if (request()->hasFile('imagePath')){ }` you have overwritten your `$image` variable :)

In that case change your code inside `if` conditional to the following

```
 if (request()->hasFile('imagePath')){
        $uploadedImage = $request->file('imagePath');
        $imageName = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images/productImages/');
        $uploadedImage->move($destinationPath, $imageName);
        $image->imagePath = $destinationPath . $imageName;
    }
```